# How to replace anonymous OnClickListener with Lambda expression?

Tags: java, android-studio, lambda

How an I replace this OnClickListener with a Lamda expression?

```
    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
            User user=new User(etnewname.getText().toString(),
                    etnewtelp.getText().toString(),
                    etnewemail.getText().toString(),
                    etnewusername.getText().toString(),
                    etnewpassword.getText().toString());
```

See below for the Android Studio message, which I don't really understand.

[image]

Comment: It would definitely help to see the entire `onClick(...)` method instead of just the few lines.

Comment: I don't know what they call the tooltip that you see as a yellow bulb there on the left of your screen. Click it and select the option to convert the code, you'll get the answer to what you're asking for.

Comment: Why bother?  It works as is.  At best its a micro-optimization, at worst a noop.  Its not worth the effort to go through old code and convert things like this.  Just turn that line rule off as overly nitty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you could outsource the creation of the `User`-Object into it's own method `createAndStoreUser()` and both parameters of the `onClick(DialogInterface interface, int i)`method will not be used, the annonymous class can be rewrittern as:

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", (di,i)-> createAndStoreUser());
```

You could also define the concrete behvaiour directly within the lambda-expression. However this wouldn't bring many advantages:

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", (di,i)-> { User user = new User(...); ... });
```